# Java Reflection: wait() method repeat thrice. Why?

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to get method names using Reflection, I have written below two classes:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {
    private void method1() {

    }
}
```

.

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Method[] m = Class.forName("com.test.Test").getMethods();

        for (Method method : m) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Instead of `getDeclaredMethods()` I have used `getMethods()` I got following output:

```
equals
hashCode
toString
getClass
notify
notifyAll
wait
wait
wait
```

**My question is:** why is the `wait` method repeated thrice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three methods named `wait` defined in class [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

```
void wait()
void wait(long timeout)
void wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

Your code is printing each method name, but not the argument type list, so they all look alike in the output. To see the parameter types, you could use something like this (which could be improved to provide better formatting:

```
for (Method method : m) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    for (Class<?> argClass : m.getParameterTypes()) {
        System.out.println("  " + argClass.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because there are three overloaded versions of the `wait` method, see the API documentation of class [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

```
wait()
wait(long timeout)
wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) indeed has three `wait` methods - one which takes no arguments, one which takes a `long`, and one which takes a `long` and an `int`.